# How to join two tables with some lines being left partially blank?

Tags: sql, sybase

To start at my original problem that is too specific for a question:
I have a table of matches in the format:

```
ID|Player1|Player2|P1Score|P2Score
--+-------+-------+-------+-------
 1|     71|     83|      2|      0
 2|     73|     71|      1|      1
 3|     71|     65|      2|      0
 4|     65|     83|      0|      2
```

Where

- 2 is a win
- 1 is a tie,
- 0 is a loss.

I need to get a table in the format:

```
Player|Wins|Draws|Losses
------+----+-----+------
    71|   2|    1|     0
    73|   0|    1|     0
    83|   1|    0|     1
    65|   0|    0|     1
```

And I don't have much of an idea how to go about it.

The closest I got was to

```
SELECT Player1, COUNT(P1Score) FROM matches WHERE P1Score = 2 GROUP BY Player1
```

and repeat that for draws and losses, then join the tables, repeat for P2, and the sum the values together, but it seems `JOIN` isn't quite the command I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2 is a win, 1 is a tie, and 0 is a loss

Given each of these conditions, we can use `case` expressions to calculate the corresponding columns by `score`. Using a `union all` to unpivot the data, and then `sum()` to aggregate it by `Player`:

```
select 
    Player
  , sum(Wins)   as Wins
  , sum(Draws)  as Draws
  , sum(Losses) as Losses
from (
  select 
      Player1 as Player
    , case when p1score = 2 then 1 else 0 end as Wins
    , case when p1score = 1 then 1 else 0 end as Draws
    , case when p1score = 0 then 1 else 0 end as Losses
  from t
  union all
  select 
      Player2 as Player
    , case when p2score = 2 then 1 else 0 end as Wins
    , case when p2score = 1 then 1 else 0 end as Draws
    , case when p2score = 0 then 1 else 0 end as Losses
  from t
  ) as s
group by Player
```

Comment: You have to compare p1score with p2score in order to make the code generic. For example, What if you have a new entry that a score (either player) is equal to 3? Your logic would be broken

Comment: @Andrade: When two players play there could be only 3 possible outcomes.  These outcomes are codified as `2`,`1`,`0`.

Comment: @Andrade The question says: "2 is a win, 1 is a tie, and 0 is a loss". This is not about goals, just an outcome. Like chess.

Comment: I'm guessing my question title is wrong, but this solves my problem quite well, and I learned about using case. There is indeed no way any score would be something other than 0, 1, or 2.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if in the matches table you have the SCORE instead of numerical codes for Win, Loss, and Draws:

```
SELECT Player, SUM(WIN) AS WINS, SUM(DRAW) AS DRAWS, SUM(LOSS) AS LOSSES 
FROM ( 
 --Create a sub query where each row is how a player did in a given match
 SELECT A.Player, 
   (CASE WHEN (A.Player = B.Player1 AND B.P1Score>B.P2Score)
      OR (A.Player = B.Player2 AND B.P2Score>B.P1Score) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WIN,       
   (CASE WHEN (A.Player = B.Player1 AND B.P1Score<B.P2Score)
      OR (A.Player = B.Player2 AND B.P2Score<B.P1Score) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) LOSS,
   (CASE WHEN B.P1Score=B.P2Score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DRAW
 FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT Player
  FROM (
   SELECT Player1 FROM matches
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Player2 FROM matches
  ) A
 LEFT JOIN matches B
)
```